# dexguard maven ERROR INVALID SDK

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, dexguard

I was actually compiling an android project using maven. When I use plugin Dexguard ,it shows this **error** :

```
Failed to execute goal com.guardsquare.dexguard.maven:dexguard-maven-plugin:8.1.00:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project .....: Execution default-generate-sources of goal com.guardsquare.dexguard.maven:dexguard-maven-plugin:8.1.00:generate-sources failed: Invalid SDK: Platform/API level 22 not available.
```

[sdk android is installed correctly img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Xbc.png)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.guardsquare.dexguard.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>dexguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <sdk>
               <platform>22</platform>
               </sdk>

               <resourceDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/mb-face-android-tablet-ui/res</resourceDirectory>
               <androidManifestFile>${project.parent.basedir}/mb-face-android-tablet-ui/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
               <dexguardConfig>${project.parent.basedir}/mb-face-android-tablet-ui/dexguard-project.txt</dexguardConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed and configured the android SDK in the right location but the error mentions that the API for platform 22 is not yet installed. Use the sdkmanager to install the right platform API.